# Update Azure Table using R

Tags: r, azure

I want tu insert this data frame to my table datatable...

```
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcConnect("CData Azure Source")
sqlTables(conn)

df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=10:1, c=11:20)
values <- paste("(",df$a,",", df$b,",",df$c,")", sep="", collapse=",")
cmd <- paste("insert into datatable values ", values)

result <- sqlQuery(conn, cmd, as.is=FALSE)
print(result)
```

But I'm having this problem...

[1] "42000 -1 Malformed SQL Statement: Expected '('. Found: values\r\nStatement:insert into datatable values  (1,10,11),(2,9,12),(3,8,13),(4,7,14),(5,6,15),(6,5,16),(7,4,17),(8,3,18),(9,2,19),(10,1,20)"
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'insert into datatable values  (1,10,11),(2,9,12),(3,8,13),(4,7,14),(5,6,15),(6,5,16),(7,4,17),(8,3,18),(9,2,19),(10,1,20)'"

Can any anybody point where i'm wrong...